# Excel can I use solver for this problem? What other options do I have?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-solver

Here is an image of the Excel table that I have **started** with:
[image: Start]
Here is an image of the solved sheet. The **solution** was calculated **by Python** and it is exactly following the given criteria.
[image: Finish]
The image was made in Google Sheets, because I transferred it there, in order to make it easy for you to access the data.
The link  to the table: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nFQEIc2ELeS5G99vezTuhaJCbmWmvB_wPkWL3dIbR1s/edit?usp=sharing

You can see the criteria that I must follow. Until now, I have calculated these fields with Python, however, now I have to pass this task to my colleague who doesn't know Python, and asked me to make a solution for her in Excel. This is a small table, so it would be easy to do it by hand here, however, the real table has around 500 rows.

I need to modify the values in `D2:E27` in order to make all values in the range of `K2:L3` greater than 60%. I can use any Excel version (365, 2021, etc.), however, I would like a no-code solution for my colleague. **Is it possible?** If so, how?

Comment: I post solutions with the Solver a lot on here, but I am not typing or downloading data from anywhere. However, from a first glance you should be able to set that up with the Solver. If there are too many variables, then Frontline do a "professional" version. Also, perhaps your colleague should be able to build it...

Comment: Also, if you're able to solve it using Python, it might be handy sharing that code, so some might follow what you mean.

Comment: first every thing is possible in excel, but the target in your question not clear enough share the result you want achieve or the solve in python to be clear and you will find many answers

Comment: @AlyAbdelaal I would add the two stored amounts and minimize that total...

Comment: @SolarMike Unfortunately my colleague knows only one Excel formula: SUM. She just cannot solve it.

Comment: @AlyAbdelaal I have updated the question. Are my goals clear?

Answer (score 0):

to solve, it need 4 similar steps :

type: A & Amount of LS

type: A & Amount of FL

type: B & Amount of LS

type: B & Amount of FL

I will talk about first case and the others will be the same
first calculate some guiding values :

`=SUMIFS($C$2:$C$27;$B$2:$B$27;"A")` without condition of amount

`=SUMIFS($C$2:$C$27;$B$2:$B$27;$J2;D$2:D$27;">0")` with condition of amount

`=F30*0,6-F31`  to know the range will be add of the area

we need to add two helper columns will be deleted or hide at the end
column help1 will has equation

`=if(and(not(D2>0);B2="A";C2>20;C2<35);C2;"")`
notice the values 20 and 35 in this equation changing (try and error) until the sum in cell f28 is greater than the guiding calculation in cell f32

column LS value will has equation

`=if(not(F2="");$K$10/COUNT($F$2:$F$27);D2)`

then take column LS value copy and paste values only in Amount of LS

and there is a link of a copy of the data you shard with those equations

[copy of the data you shard](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17rDvl6bacQ5PKS5LkjCaSKIl6ypJTZr7_ym61dvKB1s/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Unfortunately, this is **not** a solution for my problem.

Comment: I cannot hardcode anything (not even 20 and 35) because, in reality, there are 10 new Excel sheets like this every day, which have 5,000 rows.

Comment: its choice between to do all steps by hand or write a code do it for you, and VBA can do the same steps you did with python , by the way, in office365 you can include python code in excel :-)